# Proof for Brianchon's theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I seek a proof of [Brianchon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem), which states:

> When a hexagon is circumscribed around a conic section, its principal diagonals (those connecting opposite vertices) meet in a single point.

I'd prefer simpler proofs than more complex ones. Thank you.

(P.S: Similar questions have been asked, but none received proper answers.)

Comment: What's wrong with the first link offered by Google: http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/Brianchon.html#:~:text=In%20every%20circumscriptible%20in%20a,RJ%20%3D%20QH%20%3D%20MN%20etc.

Comment: @Oldboy unfortunately I'm not familiar with radical axes.

Comment: How about Ceva's theorem?

Comment: @brainjam I am somewhat familiar with Ceva's theorem; would you mind demonstrating the proof?

Comment: Is it ok to demonstrate for a circle only?  Most Brianchon proofs work this way.

Comment: @brainjam yes, that'd be excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out a proof using Ceva's theorem, but it requires some obscure supplementary lemmas that make me doubt that the proof would be as simple as OP is hoping.  Quoting [Cut The Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Brianchon.shtml):

> The easiest way to prove Brianchon's theorem is by way of duality
> implied by the properties of poles and polars.

But that is just a way of reducing it to Pascal's theorem, which is fine if you're happy with not having to prove Brianchon's theorem directly.

An elegant modern proof (Coxeter attributes it to Smogorzhevskiĭ) is given on [Pamfilos' site](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/Brianchon.html).

My version of a Ceva proof was guided by exercises 159-161 in Smith's [*Modern Geometry*](https://archive.org/details/introductorymod00smitgoog/page/n291/mode/1up).  But there are several proofs in Hatton's [*Projective Geometry, Chapter XIV*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n201/mode/2up).  They are laid out [side by side with proofs of Pascal's Theorem](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n203/mode/2up), including a Ceva proof. (**Proof by Carnot's Theorem**, pg 191.  Aptly named because a dual of Carnot's Theorem, attributed to Chasles, is the crux of the proof).  These proofs are fully general for conics, but the proofs for the circle case are presented in Chapter XII.

Milne ([*Cross-Ratio Geometry, pg 158*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.90533/page/n183/mode/2up)) gives a nice short proof, but as usual it requires some understanding of projective geometry.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing those links, and thank you for spending the time to attempt a proof! I will get back to you once I have absorbed them.